# ambiguity access of memberfunctions in C++?

Tags: visual-c++

```
class base1
{
public:
void display()
{
    cout<<"Base1"<<endl;
}
};
class base2
{public:
void display()
{
    cout<<"Base2"<<endl;
}};
class derived :public base1, public base2
{
};
```

Can anyone explain how to call base::display() through derived class object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would do this:

```
this->base1::display(); // call the display() method as defined in base1

this->base2::display(); // call the display() method as defined in base2
```

Comment: I am getting errpr when i am trying to call derived d; d.display().

Answer (score 0):

```
derived d;
d.base1::display();
```